# Reshape a numeric variable in a dataframe according to a factors in another column

Tags: r

I've been experimenting with a lot of R codes such as `melt()`, `split()`, `reshape()`, but none of them was able to really solve my problem. I would like to create a new df based on the one underneath that doesn't have the `Long_group` and `B_lymph_count` any more but instead has three different columns, namely "Aubagio_0", "Aubagio_1" and "Aubagio_2" that contain the values of the corresponding `B_lymph_counts` for the specific `MS.number` = patient ID.

## Current df:

```
MS.number  B_Lymph_count Long_group 
13  "MS072/1"  " 57014"      "Aubagio_0"
14  "MS072/1"  "116730"      "Aubagio_1"
46  "MS1246/1" "117843"      "Aubagio_0"
47  "MS1246/1" "209583"      "Aubagio_1"
52  "MS1253/1" " 71434"      "Aubagio_0"
53  "MS1253/1" "130382"      "Aubagio_1"
100 "MS717/1"  " 63916"      "Aubagio_0"
101 "MS717/1"  " 62434"      "Aubagio_1"
102 "MS717/1"  " 43533"      "Aubagio_2"
```

## Df I want to produce

```
MS.number  Aubagio_0 Aubagio_1 Aubagio_2
MS717/1       63916        62434     43533
MS1253/1      71434        130382     NA
...
```

Hope this is possible in R.
Thank you already very much for the reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(data = d, MS.number ~ Long_group, value.var = "B_Lymph_count", fill=0)

             Aubagio_0 Aubagio_1 Aubagio_2
MS072/1      57014    116730         0
MS1246/1    117843    209583         0
MS1253/1     71434    130382         0
MS717/1      63916     62434     43533
```

The `fill` parameter specifies the value in empty cells. You can also set it `NA` (by default) for instance.

Data

```
d <- structure(list(MS.number = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("MS072/1", "MS1246/1", "MS1253/1", "MS717/1"
), class = "factor"), B_Lymph_count = c(57014L, 116730L, 117843L, 
209583L, 71434L, 130382L, 63916L, 62434L, 43533L), Long_group = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Aubagio_0", "Aubagio_1", 
"Aubagio_2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("MS.number", "B_Lymph_count", 
"Long_group"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("13", "14", 
"46", "47", "52", "53", "100", "101", "102"))
```